# "aws dynamodb list-tables" not showing the tables present

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

When I use:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables
```

I am getting:

```
{
    "TableNames": []
}
```

I gave the region as default as I did the same while `aws configure`.

I also tried with specific region name.

When I check in AWS console also I don't see any DynamoDB tables, but i am able to access the table programmatically. Able to add and modify item as well.

But no result when enter I use `aws dynamodb list-tables` and also no tables when I check in console.

Comment: Is your access key have valid permission?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is clearly a result of the commands looking in the wrong place.

DynamoDB tables are stored in an account within a region. So, if there is definitely a table but none are showing, then the credentials being used either belong to a different AWS Account or the command is being sent to the wrong region.

You can specify a region like this:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --region ap-southeast-2
```

If you are able to access the table dynamically, the make sure the same credentials being used by your program are also being used for the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 1):

We need to specify the endpoint in the command which will work . As the above dynamodb is used programmatically and used as wed app.

this command will work :

aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8080 --region us-west-2

Answer (score 0):

Check the region you set up in AWS configuration vs what is displayed at the top of the AWS console. I had my app configured to `us-east-2` but the AWS console had `us-east-1` as the default. I was able to view my table once  the correct region was selected in the AWS console.